# Component vs Entity Default Generic Values

Tags: vhdl

Consider the following code:

```
entity foo is
  generic
  (
    X : natural := 9
  );
end entity foo;

architecture behav of foo is
begin
  process
  begin
    report foo'instance_name & " : " & integer'image(X) severity note;
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture behav;

entity bar is
end entity bar;

architecture behav of bar is
  component foo is
  generic
  (
    X : natural := 3
  );
  end component foo;
begin
  foo1 : entity work.foo;
  foo2 : foo;
end architecture behav;
```

Executing this code, we get:

```
# ** Note: :bar(behav):foo2@foo(behav): : 3
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /bar/foo2
# ** Note: :bar(behav):foo1@foo(behav): : 9
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /bar/foo1
```

It appears that the choice of default for unbound generics depends on the type of instantiation.  This has become a problem in one particular case, where the generic and entity mismatch.  A frequent use case for us is the following

```
entity foo is
  generic
  (
    X : natural := 9
  );
end entity foo;

package foo_pkg is
  component foo is
  generic
  (
    X : natural
  );
  end component foo;
end package foo_pkg;
```

Which leads to a compilation error if `X` is left unbound when using indirect instantiation, such as:

```
architecture rtl of bar is
begin
  foo_inst : foo;
end architecture rtl;
```

I want to confirm that this is specific to VHDL.  I read through the standard (section 5.2), but it is difficult to ascertain if this behavior is correct.

Comment: See topics in https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/using-default-value-of-a-generic-in-vhdl.494535/

Comment: @user1155120 My first example was only to demonstrate that there was a difference in which value of `X` was output.  The question is whether that behavior is correct with respect to the 1076 standard.  If so, then the compilation error seen in the later code makes sense.

Comment: The 'first example' behavior and error are defined in  6.5.6.2 "The value of a generic constant may be specified by the corresponding actual in a generic association list. If no such actual is specified for a given formal generic constant (either because the formal generic is unassociated or because the actual is open), and if a default expression is specified for that generic, the value of this expression is the value of the generic. It is an error if no actual is specified for a given formal generic constant and no default expression is present in the corresponding interface element."

Comment: A [mcve] could be [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGQs6.jpg) (with a use clause) for the code immediately preceding what appears to be your question. An error occurs during analysis architecture rtl of bar analysis If the [yes/no question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions/258636#258636) *I want to confirm that this is specific to VHDL* were clear the answer would be simply yes and little use to future readers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @user1155120.  I was trying only to ascertain whether this behavior is correct per 1076, and not a specific tool bug.  It is clear that some vendors are more lax in their implementation than others.  Having changed simulator vendors, we are now being hit by this particular case.  Since the tools differed in behavior, I was trying to determine what is the appropriate behavior.

Comment: Which `this` are you talking about? The error or how the generics values are determined? Which tools give different answers?  (Whose?)

Comment: How the generics are determined.  If they are determined by the type of instantiation, then the error message makes sense.  After further digging, it turned out it was a misunderstanding from the original reporter of the issue.  Both sets of tools we have used report an error during compilation.  Apologies reduced SNR.